# eCognition- is there an 'undo'

Tags: ecognition, undo-redo

I'm using eCognition developer trial, and when developing a ruleset in the process tree sometimes I make an error. However, just deleting that line of code (after extracting) doesn't undo that line in my image.

Is there a way to 'undo' only my most recent line of code?

I have only been able to delete the code then re-run my entire process tree, which takes a really long time.